# How to add an icon using img in php

Tags: php

Hi i am using the code below to link on specific category on my site:

```
    'samerica' => array(

                'label' => 'South America',

                'url' => ms_path_html('south-america'),

            ),
```

How can i use img tag to add an icon before the link label "South Amerika" ?

Comment: DO you want <img tag

Comment: what is the syntax ?

Comment: I am saying that do you want image tag <img>

Comment: We don't even know how this array will be handled later by your view, what do you expect from us ? Show us your view code, or explain how this array is going to be used at least. Are you using some sort of framework maybe ?

Comment: Do some try. They ask questions.

Comment: @Utkarsh - i am using this code but it breaks the whole site <img src="icons/samerica.png"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely need to apply some css in order to style and possition the image properly but this can add the image for you:

```
'samerica' => array(
            'imagePath'=> '/your/image/path.xyz',
            'label' => 'South America',

            'url' => ms_path_html('south-america'),

        ),
```

In the HTML

```
 <img src="<?= $samerica['imagePath'] ?>" alt="bla bla bla" />
```